# Separatory funnel and others glassware

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to reproduce some elements of glassware in chemistry, in particular to obtain a diagram equivalent to this one:

[image]

I looked for a package but I couldn't find one that matches (`pst-labo` does not contain a separatory funnel image).

Comment: Actually, the `pst-labo` package immediately comes into mind. If a specific instrument is not incuded in this package, you would have to create it on your own, I fear.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I contacted the authors of the package, they will try to add it soon